# How to move one image over another multiple images with animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I need to create a tab bar like view in SwiftUI.
I want to overlay a circle image as an indicator on the currently selected tab.

For example, when the 0 tab is tapped, the `selectedIndex` property changes to 0 and the circle image moves over the 0 tab with animation.

[image: tab bar like view]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedIndex = 2

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "0.square")
                    .onTapGesture { selectedIndex = 0 }
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "1.square")
                    .onTapGesture { selectedIndex = 1 }
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "2.square")
                    .onTapGesture { selectedIndex = 2 }
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "3.square")
                    .onTapGesture { selectedIndex = 3 }
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "4.square")
                    .onTapGesture { selectedIndex = 4 }
            }
            .padding()

            Image(systemName: "circle")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedIndex) { newValue in
            print("newValue is \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know how to match the X coordinate of the circle image with the X of the desired tab icon.

Any ideas are welcome.

---

Edit:

The circle image needs to be animated to move around. Instead of each tab having a circle image, one circle needs to move around from tab to tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your deployment target is iOS 14 or later, use [the `matchedGeometryEffect` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)#). iOS 14 was released in 2020.

You need to apply it to each number view (passing `isSource: true`), and also on the circle view (passing `isSource: false`).

Result:

[image: A row of five square buttons labeled 0 through 4. A circle is overlaid on the 2 button. I tap 0 and the circle's position animates to move the circle over the 0 button. The process repeats as I tap the 3, the 1, and finally the 2.]

Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var selectedIndex = 2
  @Namespace var buttonsNamespace

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      ForEach(Array(0 ..< 5), id: \.self) { i in
        Button {
          selectedIndex = i
        } label: {
          Spacer()
          Image(systemName: "\(i).square")
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .frame(height: 44)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(
              id: i,
              in: buttonsNamespace,
              properties: .position,
              anchor: .center,
              isSource: true
            )
          Spacer()
        }
      }
    }
    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
    .overlay {
      Image(systemName: "circle")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(
          id: selectedIndex,
          in: buttonsNamespace,
          properties: .position,
          anchor: .center,
          isSource: false
        )
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: selectedIndex)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that, for accessibility, a `Button` is better than an `Image` with a tap gesture.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the sizes of the tab images and the circle then:

- you can use a `GeometryReader` to deliver the available width
- the x-offset for the circle can be computed from the current selection and applied with animation.

This seems to work, more notes follow below:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private let imageSize = CGFloat(44)
    private let circleSize = CGFloat(32)
    @State var selectedIndex = 2

    private func tabImage(n: Int) -> some View {
        Image(systemName: "\(n).square")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(14)
            .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
            .onTapGesture { selectedIndex = n }
    }

    private func xOffsetForCircle(viewWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let nTabs = CGFloat(5)
        let cumulativeImageWidth = nTabs * imageSize
        let gapWidth = (viewWidth - cumulativeImageWidth) / (nTabs - 1)
        let offsetTab0 = (imageSize / 2) - (circleSize / 2)
        return offsetTab0 + CGFloat(selectedIndex) * (imageSize + gapWidth)
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
                    .offset(x: xOffsetForCircle(viewWidth: proxy.size.width))
                    .animation(.easeInOut, value: selectedIndex)

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    tabImage(n: 0)
                    Spacer()
                    tabImage(n: 1)
                    Spacer()
                    tabImage(n: 2)
                    Spacer()
                    tabImage(n: 3)
                    Spacer()
                    tabImage(n: 4)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedIndex) { newValue in
                print("newValue is \(newValue)")
            }
        }
        .frame(height: max(imageSize, circleSize))
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I moved the circle to the top of the `ZStack` so that it is behind the tab images. This way, you don't need to disable hit testing.
- The computation of the offset is made easier by using `.leading` alignment for the `ZStack`.
- The computation of the offset would be easier still if you were to space the tab images using `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` instead of using spacers, because then each tab will occupy exactly 1/5 of the available width and it wouldn't matter what the image size is.

Answer (score 0):

It is extreamly easy to achieve if you refactor your code a bit like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedIndex = 2
    let indices = (0...4)

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(indices, id: \.self) { tab in
                ZStack {
                    Image(systemName: "\(tab).square")
                        .padding()
                        .onTapGesture { selectedIndex = tab }
                    if selectedIndex == tab {
                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedIndex) { print("newValue is \($0)") }
    }
}
```

<sub>Give this an upvote and I show you how to animate the circle to move between selected tabs</sub>